# Join two tables, different date frequency MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, left-join

I'm using MySQL to calculate returns for my portfolio. So, I have a table for portfolios, the holding period is 6 months say:

```
table Portfolio

DATE_           TCIKER       WEIGHT
2007-01-31       AAPL         0.2
2007-01-31       IBM          0.2
2007-01-31       FB           0.3
2007-01-31       MMM          0.3
2007-07-31       AAPL         0.1
2007-07-31       FB           0.8
2007-07-31       AMD          0.1
  ...            ...          ...
```

And I have a monthly stat table for these companies(the whole universe of stocks) including monthly returns:

```
table stats
DATE_           TICKER      RETURN    OTHER_STATS
2007-01-31       AAPL         0.01       ...
2007-01-31       IBM          0.03       ...
2007-01-31       FB           0.13       ...
2007-01-31       MMM         -0.07       ...
2007-02-31       AAPL         0.03       ...
2007-02-31       IBM          0.04       ...
2007-02-31       FB           0.06       ...
2007-02-31       MMM         -0.10       ...
```

I'm re-balancing the portfolio every 6 month. So during these 6 months, the weights of each stock won't change. What I want to get is something like this:

```
ResultTable
DATE_           TICKER      RETURN    OTHER_STATS     WEIGHT
2007-01-31       AAPL         0.01       ...            0.2
2007-01-31       IBM          0.03       ...            0.2
2007-01-31       FB           0.13       ...            0.3
2007-01-31       MMM         -0.07       ...            0.3
2007-02-31       AAPL         0.03       ...            0.2
2007-02-31       IBM          0.04       ...            0.2
2007-02-31       FB           0.06       ...            0.3
2007-02-31       MMM         -0.10       ...            0.3
2007-03-31       AAPL         0.03       ...            0.2
2007-03-31       IBM          0.14       ...            0.2
2007-03-31       FB           0.16       ...            0.3
2007-03-31       MMM         -0.06       ...            0.3
  ...            ...          ...        ...            ...
2007-07-31       AAPL         ...        ...            0.1
2007-07-31       FB           ...        ...            0.8
2007-07-31       AMD          ...        ...            0.1
2007-08-31       AAPL         ...        ...            0.1
2007-08-31       FB           ...        ...            0.8
2007-08-31       AMD          ...        ...            0.1
```

I tired

```
select s.*, p.WEIGHT from portfolio p
left join stats s
on p.DATE_ = s.DATE_
and p.TICKER= s.TICKER;
```

It would only give me the dates of my portfolio re-balance date. 
Is there any efficient way to calculate the monthly returns?

Comment: What formula do you want to use to calculate the monthly returns? Is it something like average(return) * weight? Also, in your SQL, shouldn't you have a WHERE clause to limit the returns to the 6 month period? Also a group by so you get one row per ticker/6 month period? The p.DATE_ = s.DATE_ shouldn't be in the ON clause of the JOIN if you want all of the returns for the period.

Comment: Actually it's sum(return* weight)

Comment: Care to answer any of the other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, if I understand you formula:

```
SELECT 
    p.`DATE_`,
    p.`TICKER`,
    SUM(s.`RETURN` * p.`WEIGHT`) as `return`,
    p.WEIGHT
FROM `portfolio` p
LEFT JOIN `stats` s
ON p.`TICKER` = s.`TICKER`
WHERE s.`DATE_` BETWEEN p.`DATE_` AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(p.`DATE_`, INTERVAL 6 MONTHS),INTERVAL -1 DAY)
GROUP BY p.`DATE_`, p.`TICKER`
ORDER BY p.`DATE_`, p.`TICKER`;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was away from the computer.  Let's put calculating the returns aside. What I am trying to get first is to get portfolio's companies' stats on the following 6 months. Say the portfolio is constructed on 2007-01-31, I would like to get portfolio stocks stats for 2007-02-28...etc. To be more specific, if I have 4 stocks in my portfolio, I would like to get those four stocks stats from `stats table` for the following 6 months, with an additional column of weights. Those weights are same with those when they are initially constructed.

Comment: I tried the query 
`select s.*, p.WEIGHT from portfolio p
left join stats s
on p.TICKER= s.TICKER
where p.DATE_ = '2007-01-31; `
I was expected to the number of rows as the number of stocks in my portfolio. But I'm getting much more than that number.

Comment: Did you try the query above? Ignoring the calculation of return, did it return rows as you describe? That is, one per period (6 months) per ticker.

Comment: To get the detail rows (ie. all stats in the period) look at the where clause. By removing the group by and the sum, it should show the stats within the 6 month period.